# TYPO3 Fluid: escape array key

Tags: vue.js, typo3, fluid

I would like to escape the array key in TYPO3 Fluid template:

This works:

```
additionalAttributes="{v-model: 'title'}"
```

But this does not

```
additionalAttributes="{v-model.number: 'counter'}"
additionalAttributes="{'v-model.number': 'counter'}"
```

I need something to escape the dot in `v-model`.`number`?

Exception message:

```
The argument "additionalAttributes" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Form\TextfieldViewHelper" (More information)
```

The expected result is:

```
<input v-model.number="counter"
```

Answer (score 1):

Which TYPO3-version are you using?

According to your code and expected result, I tested the following and this worked:

```
<f:form.submit
  name="pmAction"
  value="Next category"
  style="display: none;"
  id="dialogSubmit"
  additionalAttributes="{'v-model.number': 'counter'}"
/>
```

gave me

```
<input v-model.number="counter" id="dialogSubmit" style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Next category" name="tx_template_data[pmAction]">
```

in TYPO3 9.5.11

Comment: I am currently in an updating project - the error is not in 4.5 but started in 6.2 - so there is really no simple Fluid escape for array keys available?

Comment: To which version are you willing to update? Because I tested this in 9.5 and it worked. So if you are going to this step,  this won't be a problem?
And no, AFAIK there is no possibility to escape array keys, but the writing like above should work. I am not sure, why this worked in 4.5 and not in 6.2, when it is working in 9.5. Seems to be a bug in Fluid

Comment: OK thank you, I will write some workaround in the ViewHelpers until we reach 9.5

Answer (score -1):

you can try its.

```
<input type="text" v-model="number"/>
    <Footer v-bind:additionalAttributes="{[number]: 'counter'}"/>

data(){
  return {
     number: 12
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried both, but this did not work, same exception as before

Comment: why to used to v-model.number object so

Comment: can you tell me what you want to?

Comment: I updated the description to clarify it. Unfortunately I am not looking for a workaround in Vue, as this is just a simplified example for a larger code. 
I need a working TYPO3 fluid syntax for that dot in "v-model.number"